# Is it possible to adjust Control.Lens.Indexed to work with positions?

Tags: haskell

Mind this simple program:

```
zipWith f a b       = snd $ mapAccumLOf each (\ (x:xs) a -> (xs, f a x)) (foldrOf each (:) [] b) a
toIndex shape pos   = sumOf each $ zipWith (*) pos $ shape & partsOf each %~ scanl (*) 1
fromIndex shape idx = zipWith mod (shape & partsOf each %~ scanl div idx) shape
atPos shape pos     = ix (toIndex shape pos)

main = do
    let shape = [4,4]
    let myTable = [
            0,1,2,3,
            4,5,6,7,
            8,9,10,11,
            12,13,14,15]
    print $ myTable ^?! atPos shape [1,1] -- will print 5
```

The idea here is that `atPos` creates a lens just like `ix`, except that it converts a n-dimensional position on a grid to a flat index before indexing. For example, `atPos [1,1,0] [4,4,4]` reads at the index `5`, and `atPos [3,3,3] [4,4,4]` reads at the index `63`. The problem is that calling the "shape" argument all the time is inconvenient, so I created a type that recorded the shape:

```
data Grid f a = Grid { 
    _shape  :: [Int], 
    _buffer :: f a 
    } deriving Show
makeLenses ''Grid

pget pos (Grid shape buffer)   = buffer ^?! atPos shape pos
pmod pos f (Grid shape buffer) = buffer & atPos shape pos %~ f

main = do
    let grid = Grid [4,4] [0..16]
    print $ pget [1,1] grid
    print $ pmod [1,1] (+100) grid
```

Now it is much more convenient, but since I'm not using lens anymore, I can't get use `pget, pmod` for different grids such as REPA.

My question is: is there any way to modify the indexes lens to work for **n-dimensional indexes**, so that you could, for example, view, modify and map REPA, `Grid`, Matrix etc.?